# highcharts , Hide a chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt, highcharts, smartgwt

My GWT application consists of a "Dashboard" that has a few charts . I need to be able to hide and show charts as and when necessary.

As you can see in the jsfiddle below, i was able to hide the chart, but the invisible chart eats up mouse events(when the mouse hovers over the invisible chart the tooltips are still displayed).I need to stack another canvas on top of the chart when the chart is hidden.But since the chart is taking up the mouse events , my canvas cannot receive any. Any ideas as to how to fix this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/archerabi/vnBsx/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because you're only hiding the legend instead of the whole container. I changed `.highcharts-legend` to `.highcharts-container` and I think it solved that issue. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/vnBsx/2/)

Comment: bad oversight on my part. Thanks.